# How to apply constraints to IK in godot 3.1

Tags: godot, inverse-kinematics

`SkeletonIK` seems to ignore any and all constraints.

I have set:

- normal bone constraints (in blender)
- IK constraints (in blender)
- `PhysicalBone` constraints (in godot)

None of these do anything for IK, I can move my model
into absolutely absurd poses, pulling the arm through the body,
things like that…

PS: I tried exporting from blender to .dae both with its built-in
exporter as well as godots "better collada" exporter – makes no difference.

IK Animations also don't seem to change the pose of the "physical" skeleton in any way and activating ragdoll and IK at the same time leads to utter mayhem, tho I'm not sure this has anything to do with my IK problem.

Illustrating the problem with not having constraints in IK:

[image]

Illustrating IK + ragdoll going bonkers:

[image]

> Example project data:
>   https://paste.xinu.at/XaP6c/
>   Since making the screenshots, I put the
>   `PhysicalBone`s into hierarchical order
>   which kind of fixed some things with the
>   ragdoll while breaking others – but behavior
>   for IK is still the same.

I would have expected at least ONE of the three ways I defined constraints to actually be applied to IK animations, this is not the case at all.

This isn't how it's supposed to work, right?

If anyone managed to get IK working with constraints, I'd be glad to know the trick…